# Multipart Identifier Could Not be Bound and Ambiguous Column SQL Error Messages

Tags: sql

I get the following error message when I run  the code below, can anyone point me in the right direction?

> The multi-part identifier "o.fkCountryId" could not be bound.
> Ambiguous column name 'cCountry'.

Code:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    [nOrderID] AS 'Order ID',
    [cCountry] AS 'Country'
FROM 
    [Order] AS o,
    [ListCountries] AS lc
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [ListCountries] ON lc.[pkCountryId] = o.[fkCountryId]
ORDER BY 
    [nOrderID] DESC
```

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Schemas of the used tables would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should be fine with proper `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT TOP 100 o.[nOrderID] AS Order_ID, lc.[cCountry] AS Country
FROM [Order] o LEFT JOIN
     [ListCountries] lc
     ON lc.[pkCountryId] = o.[fkCountryId]
ORDER BY o.[nOrderID] DESC;
```

I'm guessing where the columns come from.

Comment: The columns are [nOrderID] from the [Order] table  and [cCountry] from the [ListCountries]  table.

Comment: Just tried it and it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
The multi-part identifier "o.fkCountryId" could not be bound.
```

That means that there is no column called fkCountryId in the Order table.

```
Ambiguous column name 'cCountry'.
```

That means that there is a column called cCountry in both the Order table and the ListCountries table.